# How can i find the largest number of times a word is repeated on consecutive lines?

Tags: php, bash, loops, if-statement

I have files which have contents that contain only "win" or "loss" like so:

```
win
win
loss
loss
loss
loss
win
loss
win
win
win
win
win
loss
loss
win
win
```

I would like to find the largest winning streak, which is the largest number of times that the word "win" has appeared on consecutive lines.
In the above example, "win" appears consecutively 2 , 1, 5 and 2 times.
so the largest win streak would be "5".

How can i use the Linux terminal or PHP to calculate this?
The only way i can think to do it is to look for "win" then use a large number of nested if statements to check the next line, but if the win streak was over 100+ then this would result in large amounts of code.
Is their examples of how this can be done more efficiently?

Comment: for a PHP solution you're going to have to perform a loop and track various values of the last item, the counter, the item with the largest counter. But ideally, you should come to us with some code samples you've tried first.

Comment: `uniq -c file | sort -rn | grep win | head -1`

Comment: @jhnc: I just wanted to propose something similar. If you have a really really big file, you can use a slight variation `uniq -c file | grep -F win | sort -rn | head -1`, as sorting will be the most resource intense job here and you don't match patterns, so grep will have an easy job.

Comment: @jottbe yes, grep first is more efficient. Not sure `-F` makes any difference to grep performance in this case (based on `time grep -F win 10GBFileOfUniqLines | cat >/dev/null` and without `-F`)

Comment: `grep -F` would be more efficient (originally `fgrep` meant `fast grep` because it was faster as it was searching for strings rather than regexps) but you can't use grep without some kind of boundary tests (word boundary escape sequences or -w which are both non-POSIX extensions) anyway as it'd pick up `twinning` as well as `win`

Comment: @EdMorton: you're right, `-F` doesn't match the whole line by default. If you like to have this, you can combine it with `-x`. But I think regarding the question this doesn't matter, because the file only contains win/loss.

Comment: @jottbe good point, I hadn't noticed that it's ONLY win or loss in the input. `-x` wouldn't have worked because by the time you `grep` the line also contains a number which is why I suggested `-w` or word boundary escape sequences.

Answer (score 1):

As there's still no PHP solution given to this question, and admittedly *slightly* more verbose than the solutions given in the comments... This might help:

```
<?php
$content = file_get_contents('winloss.txt');
$arr = explode("\r\n", $content);
$rep = repetition($arr);
echo $rep['response'];

function repetition(array $arr, $str1 = 'win', $str2 = 'loss')
{
    $prevVal = null;
    $count = 1;
    foreach($arr as $key => $value) {
        if($prevVal == $value) {
            $count++;
            $storeRep[$value][] = $count;
        } else {
            $count = 1;
        }
        $prevVal = $value;
    }
    $maxConsec[$str1] = max($storeRep[$str1]);
    $maxConsec[$str2] = max($storeRep[$str2]);
    $maxConsec['response'] = "largest winning streak : " . $maxConsec[$str1];
    return $maxConsec;
}
```

output:
largest winning streak : 5

`var_dump($rep)`:

```
array(3) {
  ["win"]=>
  int(5)
  ["loss"]=>
  int(4)
  ["response"]=>
  string(26) "largest winning streak : 5"
}
```

Comment: I don't speak PHP but wouldn't something like this be more efficient? `<?php $c = $max = 0; while ($i = fgets(STDIN)) { if ($i == "win\n") { if (++$c > $max) $max++; } else $c = 0; } echo "$max\n";`

Answer (score 0):

```
$ uniq -c file | sort -rn | awk '$2=="win"{print $1; exit}'
5
```

You could do it all in awk of course:

```
awk '
    $0!=prev { if (cnt > max[prev]) max[prev]=cnt; prev=$0; cnt=0 }
    { cnt++ }
    END { if (cnt > max[prev]) max[prev]=cnt; print max["win"] }
' file
5
```

Answer (score 0):

As there still is not python version (which is a shame), I wanted to provide one:

```
fp= open('file.txt', 'rt')

oldline= None
line= fp.readline()
counts= dict()
currcount= 1

while line:
    if line != oldline:
        if oldline is not None and counts.get(oldline, 0) <= currcount:
            counts[oldline]= currcount
        currcount= 1
        oldline= line
    else:
        currcount+= 1
    line= fp.readline().strip()

print(counts['win'])

if counts.get(line, 0) <= currcount:
    counts[line]= currcount
```

Btw, I would really love to know, how a python version performs in comparison to an awk version.

So now finally I can start with the COBOL version :-)

Answer (score 0):

What surpises me, is that there also still is no pandas version. How is that possible?

```
import pandas

df= pd.read_csv('file.txt', names=['win_loss'], index_col=False)
df['group']=(df['win_loss'] != df['win_loss'].shift()).cumsum()
group_counts= df.groupby(df['group']).agg({'win_loss': 'first', 'group': 'count'}).groupby('win_loss').max()
print(group_counts.loc['win'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Here a version in COBOL. Slightly more verbose, than the other versions ;-)
You can simpy run it from a JCL in z/OS (loosely speaking: the bash version of z/OS):

```
   IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
   PROGRAM-ID. WINCOUNT.
   AUTHOR.     JOTTBE.
  *
   ENVIRONMENT DIVISION.
   CONFIGURATION SECTION.
  *
   SPECIAL-NAMES.
       DECIMAL-POINT IS COMMA.
  *
   INPUT-OUTPUT SECTION.
   FILE-CONTROL.
  * ---CONTROL CARD
       SELECT VCNT    ASSIGN       TO VCNT
                      ORGANIZATION SEQUENTIAL
                      ACCESS       SEQUENTIAL
                      FILE STATUS  VCNT-STATUS.

  * ---INPUT FILE
       SELECT CNT     ASSIGN       TO CNT
                      ORGANIZATION SEQUENTIAL
                      ACCESS       SEQUENTIAL
                      FILE STATUS  CNT-STATUS.
   DATA DIVISION.
   FILE SECTION.
  * ---CONTROL CARD
   FD  VCNT
       BLOCK CONTAINS 0 RECORDS
       LABEL RECORD IS STANDARD
       RECORDING MODE IS F.
   01  VC-RECORD                     PIC X(080).

  *----INPUT FILE
   FD  CNT
       BLOCK CONTAINS 0 RECORDS
       LABEL RECORD IS STANDARD
       RECORDING MODE IS F.
   01  C-RECORD                      PIC X(004).

   WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.

   01  PARMCARD.
  * ---TEXT "SEARCH FOR: "
       05 FILLER                   PIC X(012).
       05 SEARCH-STRING            PIC X(004).
       05 FILLER                   PIC X(064).

   01  INP-LINE.
       05 STRING                   PIC X(004).

   01  WORK.
       05 LAST-STRING              PIC X(004) VALUE "    ".
       05 LAST-COUNT               PIC X(010) VALUE 0.
       05 MAX-COUNT                PIC X(010) VALUE 0.

   01  K-CONSTANTS.
       05 K-STATUS-OK              PIC X(02)   VALUE "00".
       05 K-EOF                    PIC X(02)   VALUE "10".
       05 K-ERROR                  PIC X       VALUE "E".
       05 K-OK                     PIC X       VALUE " ".
       05 K-YES                    PIC X       VALUE "Y".

   01  S-SWITCHES.
       05 S-PGM-STATUS             PIC X       VALUE " ".
       05 S-ERROR                  PIC X       VALUE " ".
       05 S-END                    PIC X       VALUE " ".
          88 END-OF-PROCESSING                 VALUE "Y".

  *
  ******************************************************************
   PROCEDURE DIVISION.
  ******************************************************************

   S00 SECTION.

       INITIALIZE PARMCARD
       INITIALIZE WORK

  *
  * ---OPEN FILES
  *

  * 1. PARAMETER CARD
       OPEN INPUT VCNT
       IF VCNT-STATUS              = K-STATUS-OK
          READ VCNT INTO PARMCARD
          IF VCNT-STATUS           = K-EOF
             DISPLAY "ERROR OPENING THE PARAMETER CARD"
             EXIT
          END-IF
       END-IF

  * 2. INPUT FILE
       OPEN INPUT CNT
       IF CNT-STATUS               = K-STATUS-OK
          CONTINUE
       ELSE
             DISPLAY "ERROR OPENING THE INPUT FILE"
             EXIT
       END-IF

       PERFORM UNTIL CNT-STATUS = K-EOF OR END-OF-PROCESSING
          READ CNT INTO INP-LINE
               AT END MOVE "Y" TO S-END
          END-READ
          IF STRING NOT = LAST-STRING
             IF SEARCH-STRING = LAST-STRING 
                   AND LAST-COUNT > MAX-COUNT
                MOVE LAST-COUNT TO MAX-COUNT
             END-IF
             MOVE STRING TO LAST-STRING
             MOVE 1      TO LAST-COUNT
          END-IF
       END-PERFORM
       IF SEARCH-STRING  = STRING 
              AND LAST-COUNT > MAX-COUNT
          MOVE LAST-COUNT TO MAX-COUNT
       END-IF
       DISPLAY SEARCH-STRING " OCCURED " MAX-COUNT " TIMES."

       EXIT.
```

Run it with a control card with the following content:

```
SEARCH FOR: WIN
```

Have fun.